# IOS: IBAction with two actions

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

In my app I have an ibaction and  inside it I have 2 different instruction with an "if"

```
 if (i == 0)  //do instruction set 1
 if (i == 1) //do instruction set 2
 // and everytime I push button i change from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0
```

the problem is that if I repeatedly press the button of this IbAction it don't work fine because the previous ibaction didn't finish its instruction set1

example = press button, it execute instruction set 1, if I push another time the button it shouldn't work because it it didn't finish its work and I want to wait the end of instruction set 1 to repeat the push of button.

Do you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `BOOL workInProgress` variable in your class:

```
- (IBAction)action {
    if (!workInProgress) {
        workInProgress = YES;
        if (i == 0) {
            // do something that in the end sets workInProgress to NO
        } else if (i == 1) {
            // do something else that in the end sets workInProgress to NO
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a bool value,set it to NO at the begining of your instruction set,and back to YES after.if the value is NO then don't do anythig